# Require js loads to slow to register jquery globally for other scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have an app wrapped up in require that needs to be dropped in to an existing page which already has some scripts in it that make use of jquery. The require app includes jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/require.js" data-main="pathtomyscript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqueryplugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As far as i understand jquery loads itself as global even in the context of AMD http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

The problem that I'm having is that my require app takes a couple of seconds to load in the page, by which time by other scripts (jquery ui etc) have already run.
The result of this is a bunch of Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined errors in the console. once my require app has loaded then jQuery is available..but it's too late.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mixing loading some scripts (such as JQuery) via RequireJS and other scripts (such as JQuery UI) via a `<script>` element as you will end up with ordering problems like you're experiencing because dependencies aren't being specified. In this case, I would suggest setting up a RequireJS shim to indicate that JQuery UI and the plugin has a dependency on JQuery, and require those two modules.

For example:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-[version-you-are-using]',
        jqueryUi: 'jquery-ui-1.8.20.min',
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: { exports: '$' },
        jqueryUi: { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$' },
        jqueryplugin: { deps: ['jquery'], exports: '$' },
    }
});

require(['jqueryUI', 'jqueryplugin'], function($) { /* ... */ });
```

Alternatively, you could take the approach of loading JQuery-related scripts ahead of any require'd modules. For example:

```
<script src="jquery-[version-you-are-using].js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqueryplugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/require.js" data-main="pathtomyscript"></script>
```

A common way to use this approach is to load all external/3rd party scripts by direct `<script>` references, while all app-specific scripts are loaded as require'd modules.